# Doubts about this multistep form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've found this multistep form 
I have two doubts:
1) How can i pass the value from first step to second step of form?
2)How can i control that the value of datepicker is not null (so stop user in first step)?

[LINK MULTISTEP FORM](https://www.cssscript.com/multi-step-form-bootstrap/)

Comment: Welcome to the platform. This is not exactly the way to ask a question. Use the code, search for solutions. When you are stuck, share your code, and share what is not working, what is happening, how does it differ from what you expected.

Comment: The "steps" are just visual tricks to show and hide things as far as I can see. You can keep the entire state of the form in the background at all times without needing to "send" anything anywhere, at least until the form is being submitted, and then you will obviously need to send the whole dataset to the server

Answer (score 0):

1) You can achieve this with JavaScript or JQuery, you said it’s a multistep form, example: it’s a 3
steps form. So you keep each step in different fieldset, then by default you hide all fieldsets except first one, and when first step is completed then hide completed step and show next step and so on.

2) When user enters all details of each step, before going to next step validate the current step input values using jQuery or JavaScript, if doesn’t met your validation then don’t show the next steps.